# How can I make form access a name from an encapsulated component?

Tags: angular, forms

I got a small Angular question related to forms - I have a parent component whose html code contains an ngform:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
```

The ts file accesses this form by calling:

```
@ViewChild('form', { static: false }) public form: NgForm
```

My problem is that I also have a child component encapsulated in that form, and obviously the form doesn't recognize the names in the html file of that child component, unlike the names that exist in the html of the parent component.

```
<div> <input name="inputName"> </div>
```

This is a simplified version of the part of the child component that I'm trying to make the form recognize. I know ControlValueAccessor will do the trick, but it seems too big and unnecessary of a change for something this small. Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: It’s not clear where the “encapsulated component” lives. Can you show the code altogether and point out how you can access props of the parent, but not if the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, create a custom form control it's really unnecessary. Really a custom form control should be to create a new "input" -not to group inputs-, e.g. a calendar, a drag, a serie of checkboxes, an special select...

You can use viewProviders (really it's hard to read the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#elementinjector) about this).

Dont' worry, in the case of template driven forms the only you need it's your child as

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <input ngModel name="fool"/>
  `,
  //see the viewProviders say that use the NgForm that exist
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }]
})
export class ChildComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

Think in a viewProvider of a ControlContainer that it's like "your'e using the `<form #form="ngForm">` of the parent"

Then your parent can be simply

```
<form #form="ngForm">
  <child></child>
</form>
```

See a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ywgxgt?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

NOTE: In the stackblitz I use standalone components -the only diference it's that using standalone components we need imports the modules, if you not use standalone components, remember in your module add the Common and FormsModule and declare the two components

NOTE2: if we are using ReactiveFormsModule, the provider should be `FormGroupDirective`

```
viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective}]
```