# Does angular detectChanges() has a conflict with its form control valueChanges emits

Tags: angular, typescript

In parent Component, I have a formGroup. I patch this formGroup Value like this.

```
ngAfterViewInit() { this.sampleform.controls['a'].patchValue ...}
```

And in parent component HTML I pass the form to child component like this.

```
<child-component [formGroup]="sampleform" ...>
```

In child component, I delcared an array of subscription with the use of valueChanges method. Inside ngOninit().

```
@Input formGroup : any; ArrayOfSubs : Array<Subscription>
    ngOninit(){
        formControl: AbstractControl = this.formGroup.get(field.name);
        this.ArrayOfSubs.push(formControl?.valueChanges.subscribe(value=>{
          console.log(value);
          if(a==1 || a ==2 ){
            console.log(value);
            this.cdRef.detectChanges();
          }
        }))
    }
```

I feels like the detectChanges is conflicting the valueChanges or something, because for whatever reason once after the code runs through `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` that is inside if statement, valueChanges is not detected anymore.But before `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` that is inside the if statement rant, the console log works fine.

Also there will be checkExpression error after I remove the cdRef to anywhere in to code, Tried markForChanges() not working, still check expression error .

Comment: when you create the subscriptions? I feel you need make it using a setter in the `@Input` of the formGroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `FormGroup` to the Child Component doesn't associate your child component as a part of parent FormGroup.

Try to use one valueChanges in parent form and pass formGroup in the child component class:

```
public aControl: FormControl<string> = new FormControl<string>('',[]);

constructor(@Optional() private formGroup: FormGroupDirective) {}

ngOnInit() {
    if (this.formGroup) {
        this.aControl = this.formGroup.control.get('a') as FormControl;
    }
}
```

In the child template:

```
<input [formControl]="aControl">
```

Comment: instead your work-around use viewProvider, like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76879691/how-can-i-make-form-access-a-name-from-an-encapsulated-component/76881366#76881366) (see the NOTE2 where it's indicte that you use FormControlDirective)

Comment: @Eliseo - Yes your solution is better. I'm just copy-paste my variant because i'm not found, in my time, a solution for reuse one component in the template-driven with NgModel and reactive forms.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem turns out my life cycle implementation is wrong and the above answer do point out one important factor.

The form control in child component does not associate with parent component form control, so the patching of the parent form control values will not emits any value changes in the child component subscription that is based on newly declared form control.

Also I am patching value in `ngAfterViewInit`, this is a bad practice.

As I am changing parent form control value, after it has been passed to child component. And the child component did use the value in `ngOninit` life cycle.

If the child component used the value from form control in anywhere else in the file, this will create the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.` error.

And this error cannot be simply fixed by `detectChanges()`.